# can I bind() to in6addr_any( ie ::) and sendto() localhost

Tags: c, networking, ipv6

I am trying to write a sample client and server

now `sever.c` would

1. create a v6 UDP socket
2. bind() to in6addr_any ie `::`
3. recvfrom() (after sendto succeeds on client side)

in `client.c` would

1. create a v6 udp socket
2. sendto() `::ffff:127.0.0.1`

My query would be is this scenario correct or am I missing something?

Because the `sendto()` on the client side is successful but `recvfrom()` hangs on the server side

Any help??

regards

Biswajeet

Answer (score 3):

in6addr_any is ::0.  As an argument to bind() this can mean either "any IPv6 address" or "any IPv6 or IPv4 address" depending on the IPV6_V6ONLY sockopt for the listening (IPv6) socket.  The default value for this sockopt depends on your platform and local configuration - for maximal portability you must set it manually to get whatever your preferred behaviour is.

If it is set to 0 then it should receive packets addressed to 127.0.0.1 (or any other local address), and this is where you will see IPv6 addresses of the form ::ffff:127.0.0.1.  If it's set to 1 then your listening socket will not receive packets addressed to IPv4 addresses at all (in mapped form or otherwise).

If you have an IPv6 sending socket it makes more sense to send to ::1 than ::ffff:127.0.0.1 (if I understand the setup right then the latter should nevertheless work assuming the listening socket accepts both stacks).